# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable - finding primes :/

Tags: python, primes

```
import math

def findprimes(k):

    Primes=[]
    Numbers=[]
    if k>3:
        r=findprimes(math.floor(k**(1/2)))
    for a in range(k):
        Numbers.append(a+1)
    if Numbers==[1,2]:
        Primes=[2]
    if Numbers==[1,2,3]:
        Primes=[2,3]
    if len(Numbers)>3:
        for v in list(r):

            for i in range(math.floor(k/v)):
                Numbers.remove[i*v]
    if len(Numbers)>3:
        Primes=Numbers
    return Primes
```

So I wrote the good old find primes since I'm using it for another program, however when I run it it I get the

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable error regarding Numbers.remove[i*v].
```

Please I'm not looking to approach it with another way, but rather overcoming it here.

Comment: All errors contain the line number where the error is, as well as the message actually containing the code from the line in question. You don't see anything wrong with the *function call*?

Answer (score 2):

`Numbers.remove()` is a method but you are trying to use subscription on it with `[..]`:

```
Numbers.remove[i*v]
```

Replace that with parenhesis:

```
Numbers.remove(i*v)
```